# Let $A,B$ be solvable subgroup of a group $G$, suppose $B \subset N_G(A)$. Prove $AB$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Need help, 
Show: Let $A,B$ be solvable subgroup of a group $G$. Suppose the $B \subset N_G(A)$. Prove that $AB$ is solvable.

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: Someone gave me a hint to show that AB is a subgroup of G, and based on the fact that any subgroup of a solvable group is solvable, AB must be solvable. AB is a subgroup because aba'b'=aa''bb'. Hence closed under product. (ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a'b^{-1} hence closed under inversion. So, I just have to read why any subgroup of a solvable group is solvable.

Comment: Well if there’s $G=G_0 \supseteq G_1 \supseteq ... \supseteq G_n=\{e\} $-solvable series for G, then just consider such series for $H \subseteq G : H_i=G_i \cap H$ and try to prove that this series will be solvable for $H$

Comment: Hint: you’ll need a second isomorphism theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $B \subseteq N_G(A)$, it is easy to show that $AB$ is actually a subgroup. Since $B$ normalizes $A$ it follows that $A \unlhd AB$. Now $AB/A \cong B/(A \cap B)$ by the 2nd isomorphism theorem. Since $A$ is solvable and $B$, whence any of $B$'s quotients is solvable, it follows that $AB$ is solvable. (In general: $G$ is solvable iff $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable ($N \unlhd G$)).